# word usage: "inquietarse" and "inquieta"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática

Which of the following sentences is/are correct which refers to English speaking of "Are you still worried about the future"?

> 1. ¿Todavía te inquietas por el futuro?
> 2. ¿Todavía inquietas por el futuro?
> 3. ¿Todavía inquieta/o por el futuro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally, you would use it as an adjective like this:

> ¿Todavía estás inquieto por el futuro?

This is exactly the same as the original sentence you want to translate, the verb is "to be" and "worried" an adjective.

If you still would like to use the verb "[inquietar](http://rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=Inquietarse&val_aux=&origen=REDRAE)", the subject is the thing worring you, in this case, "the future". So, your two first sentences are not correct. Usually, you use a pronoun for expressing who worries the thing (indirect object), as you tried in your first sentence with "te". So the sentence would be:

> ¿Todavía te inquieta el futuro?

Comment: A mí me cuesta con las definiciones de "sujeto" y "objeto". Como en esta frase "Do you still worried about the future?", el sujeto es "you" y el objeto es "the future", no? Por qué invierte?

Comment: La frase en inglés sería: "Are you still worried about the future". Sí, el sujeto es "you" y el objeto "the future". En inglés y en español, worry/inquietar funcionan así: Sujeto - inquieta/worry - yo. Es como "scare": "The dog scares me", "El perro me asusta". "The future worries me", "El futuro me inquieta".

Comment: Fíjate que en "Are you still..." estás usando el verbo "estar"/"to be". Yo estoy inquieto. Esa cosa me inquieta.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Ya veo poco. Necesito explorar más para entender.

Comment: ¿Eres de China? Si lo entiendes en inglés, lo entenderás en español porque pasa lo mismo en los dos idiomas.

Comment: Sí, soy china. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4026/discussion-between-cadenza-and-joulsauron)